# Obtaining fundamental soil parameters given only soil average density, sample volume, and mass

Tags: civil-engineering, soil

Assume that there a soil sample has a known density $\rho$, volume V, and mass m. Given only this information, is it possible to obtain fundamental soil parameters for cohesion, internal friction angle, and pore water pressure?

Basically I want to determine shear stress $\tau=c+\sigma \tan(\phi)$ just from a density. I know this is the case for drained soil, but I would like to generalize concept even more and extend it to the undrained case as well. Is there any possible way to this as well?

Comment: Are those characteristics purely dependant on the density? If not then "NO" comes to mind.

Comment: There are empirically-obtained correlations between density and several fundamental soil parameters in some studies, that's the best I have been able to find.

Comment: So will doubling the volume cause the pore water pressure to change? if the height is increased? or height kept constant but the length changes?

Comment: You need to conduct laboratory analyses on soil samples to determine the parameters you require.